# Mobile Safari Scrolling Div flickers on new page

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have a table that is contained in a div that is scrollable.  When I click on a link the div blinks on and off with the loading of a new page.  The rest of the pages does not blink.  If I remove the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; out of the CSS the flickering issue disappears.  I like the feel of the touch scroll and would like to keep it.

This is the CSS I am using for the div

```
.navWrapper {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 194px;
height: 430px;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
width:1024px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is an experiment for the div

```
<div class="navWrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="page.html"><img src="../images/thumb01a.png" width="72" height="72" alt=""></a></td>
        </tr>

   </table>

</div>
```

I have tried also linking to different pages and get the same result.  The experiment just has the same page linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try add -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden to .navWrapper.